# SQL Cast Function Syntax Error

Tags: sql, ms-access

Can anyone guide me in the right direction with this? I've tried editing my syntax every way possible and searched for 2 hours how to make this work. But I cannot get my CAST function to work properly. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT     dbo_orders.ordernumber, 
       dbo_orders.orderdate, 
       Sum([dbo_Order Details].priceperunit) AS sumofpriceperunit, 
       dbo_orders.producttotal, 
       Sum([dbo_Order Details].costperunit) AS sumofcostperunit, 
       dbo_orders.shippingtotal, 
       dbo_tracking.cost, 
       [dbo_Order Details].dropship, 
       dbo_orders.cartid 
CAST       ([dbo_Tracking].cost) AS number 
FROM       dbo_tracking 
INNER JOIN ([dbo_Order Details] 
INNER JOIN dbo_orders 
ON         [dbo_Order Details].ordernumber = dbo_orders.ordernumber) 
ON         dbo_tracking.numerickey = [dbo_Order Details].ordernumber 
GROUP BY   dbo_orders.ordernumber, 
       dbo_orders.orderdate, 
       dbo_orders.producttotal, 
       dbo_orders.shippingtotal, 
       dbo_tracking.cost, 
       [dbo_Order Details].dropship, 
       dbo_orders.cartid 
HAVING     ((( 
                                        dbo_orders.orderdate)>=(#6/1/2016#) 
                  AND        ( 
                                        dbo_orders.orderdate)<=(#6/30/2016#)));
```

Answer (score 2):

msaccess cast functions

```
Cint -- cast to integer
Clng -- long
Cdbl -- double
Csng - single
Cstr - string
Cbool - boolean

SELECT clng(fieldName) FROM tableName
```

https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/datatype/cint.php

added ',' , cast the field, remove having clause and added where clause. you might want to format the date accordingly.

```
    SELECT     dbo_orders.ordernumber, 
           dbo_orders.orderdate, 
           Sum([dbo_Order Details].priceperunit) AS sumofpriceperunit, 
           dbo_orders.producttotal, 
           Sum([dbo_Order Details].costperunit) AS sumofcostperunit, 
           dbo_orders.shippingtotal, 
           dbo_tracking.cost, 
           [dbo_Order Details].dropship, 
           dbo_orders.cartid ,    'added a comma
    CInt       ([dbo_Tracking].cost) AS number  'cast accordingly
    FROM       dbo_tracking 
    INNER JOIN ([dbo_Order Details] 
    INNER JOIN dbo_orders 
    ON         [dbo_Order Details].ordernumber = dbo_orders.ordernumber) 
    ON         dbo_tracking.numerickey = [dbo_Order Details].ordernumber 

where   'added where clause
         dbo_orders.orderdate>=   (#6/1/2016#) 
   AND   dbo_orders.orderdate <=(#6/30/2016#)

    GROUP BY   dbo_orders.ordernumber, 
           dbo_orders.orderdate, 
           dbo_orders.producttotal, 
           dbo_orders.shippingtotal, 
           dbo_tracking.cost, 
           [dbo_Order Details].dropship, 
           dbo_orders.cartid 
 'removed having clause
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, in MS Access you use one of the type conversion functions:

```
Cdec([dbo_Tracking].cost) AS number
```

If you don't want a decimal, check the [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Type-Conversion-Functions-8ebb0e94-2d43-4975-bb13-87ac8d1a2202) for the type you do want.

BTW, the correct syntax for cast includes a type.  For example:

```
cast([dbo_Tracking].cost as decimal(20, 4))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. For some reason it's still giving me Syntax Error (missing operator).

Comment: remove having and chuck a where clause before group by and count your parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma next to `dbo_orders.cartid`