# Return AVG as FLOAT in MS-Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, floating-point, average

I am trying to return the Average as a FLOAT, but when I use the code bellow, I get an error every time in Access saying MissingOperator. What am I missing in my code?

```
SELECT AVG(CAST(Quantity AS FLOAT))
FROM Orders
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Cast Function Syntax Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43359282/sql-cast-function-syntax-error)

Comment: Are you asking for Microsoft Access SQL, or a servers SQL syntax like Transact SQL of the Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: @UnhandledException Microsoft Access SQL

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT AVG(CDBL(Quantity))
FROM OrderDetails;
```

Comment: That would have been my next proposal. :-)

Comment: I would call it like: `SELECT CDbl(Avg(Quantity))`.

Comment: Sure, should perform better.

Answer (score 0):

I often just write:

```
SELECT AVG(1.0 * Quantity)
FROM Orders;
```

However, this might return the value as a decimal rather than a `float`.